# How to list RDP connections started from my machine and are currently active

Tags: remote-desktop

**I need to obtain the list of all RDP connections (list of IP) actually active from my machine.**

Is there a way? The language/method is not important

My long-term goal is to collect all the open RDP connections from all office PCs  so I can have a reporting panel for each of our remote desktops, which of our pc is currently connected with, or if this machine is currently free or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `qwinsta` for this, passing in a `/SERVER` variable to query other machines.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731503(v=ws.11).aspx